# How do I match every word in a string except for the last word?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following strings:

```
Chicago CPA
New York CPA
West Virginia Accountant
```

How do I always just chop off the last word (and the preceding whitespace) in the string, preserving all other words before the last word?

So the correct versions of the above data set would be:

```
Chicago
New York
West Virginia
```

Also, is it possible to test matching groups on Rubular or is there another online regex editor/tester that I can use to test regexes with matching groups?

**Edit 1**

Many of the answers are great in theory. I read them, I understand them and I test them on a vanilla string and they seem to work. But when I try it on my data, it doesn't. I was stumped for a while, and I just realized why.

This is the HTML I am working on:

```
<h1 class="search-term">
   Chicago&nbsp;<strong>Cpa</strong>
</h1>
```

So this the text, I am attempting to do this string manipulation on:

```
Chicago&nbsp;<strong>Cpa</strong>
```

So here is what happens when I try each of the answers below.

---

@Darshan's:

```
[56] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text
=> "Chicago Cpa"
[57] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.class
=> String
[58] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.match(/(.*) \w+\z/)[1]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):57:in `<class:PageCrawler>'
[59] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text[/.*(?=\s\w+\z)/]
=> nil
```

---

@Lucas's own:

```
[60] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text
=> "Chicago Cpa"
[61] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.class
=> String
[62] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.split()[0...-1].join(' ')
=> ""
```

---

@Eric's own:

```
[65] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text
=> "Chicago Cpa"
[66] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.class
=> String
[67] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.split().reverse.drop(1).reverse.join(" ")
=> ""
```

---

@Casimir's own (this one is the best so far, actually):

```
[68] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text
=> "Chicago Cpa"
[69] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.class
=> String
[70] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.sub(/\W+\w+\W*$/, '')
=> "Chicago"
```

---

@Santosh's own:

```
[71] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text
=> "Chicago Cpa"
[72] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text.class
=> String
[73] pry(YPCrawler::PageCrawler)> @document.css('header h1.search-term').first.text[/(.*)\s/,1]
=> nil
```

---

My apologies for not doing this earlier, but I didn't anticipate this being an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll preface by saying I'm not particularly good with regular expressions, and I'm not sure off the top of my head (nor do I feel inclined to benchmark or think hard about) whether this would tend to be more or less efficient than @LucasP's non-regex approach.  But this is the obvious approach that comes to mind for me:

```
s.match(/(.*) \w+\z/)[1]
```

That matches at the end of the string one or more word characters preceded by a space, and puts everything before that into a group that you then grab.

```
data = ['Chicago CPA',
        'New York CPA',
        'West Virginia Accountant']

data.map{|s| s.match(/(.*) \w+\z/)[1]}
# => ["Chicago", "New York", "West Virginia"]
```

**Edit:** A variant on this approach, suggested by @CarySwoveland, is to use a lookahead expression to ignore the part we want to discard, rather than my initial approach of putting the part we want into a capturing group that we then access.  Here's a version of that approach:

```
data.map{|s| s[/.*(?=\s\w+\z)/]}
# => ["Chicago", "New York", "West Virginia"]
```

**Edit 2:** With your added information, it's now clear that the issue you were facing is that you have non-breaking spaces, which even with `\s` aren't matched (`\s` only matches ASCII whitespace, equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f]`).  So using either the POSIX bracket expression `[[:space:]]` or explicitly matching `\u00A0` for the non-breaking space character works, assuming all are non-breaking spaces.  I prefer the former, since you might have other whitespace there sometimes:

```
data.map{|s| s[/.*(?=[[:space:]]\w+\z)/]}
```

Comment: I see where you are going, but this regexp doesn't seem to match `Chicago CPA` per Rubular.com. It only matches

Comment: @marcamillion Again, it works for me both on my machine and at rubular.com.  I'd dump your dataset into a hex editor and see what's going on with your whitespace.

Comment: I hadn't notice your answer when I posted mine. The two were pretty close so I killed mine.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah, looks like we had the same general approach, thanks.  I liked your lookahead version that ignores the part we want to discard, rather than grouping the part we want and grabbing the group.

Comment: I was struggling with figuring out why your suggestions weren't working on my actual data, yet when I try with a vanilla string it works. I have updated the question with more details about what my data actually looks like. Can you update your answer accordingly please? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the updated info.  The problem was the non-breaking spaces; this is addressed in my updated answer (see Edit 2).

Answer (score 2):

One way of achieving this is the following:

```
myString.split()[0...-1].join(' ')
```

Where `myString` is each string you want to perform this operation on.

1. First you split from string to a list containing each word.
2. Then select the sublist that contains all elements except the last one.
3. Finally you go back from list to a string.

Comment: So I had initially tried something similar, but the weirdest thing is happening when I try to split these strings. `> "Chicago Cpa".split
=> ["Chicago Cpa"]`. It doesn't create a new element for each word...which I find weird. What could be causing this?

Comment: @marcamillion When I copy and paste that, I get `["Chicago", "Cpa"]` as expected.  Is it possible you have some wonky whitespace in your strings?

Comment: That's very bizzarre. Not sure why mine isn't splitting properly. I am not seeing any wonky whitespaces.

Comment: Don't you mean `[0..-2]`?

Comment: `[0..-2]` or `[0...-1`], it's the same. `Ranges constructed using .. run from the beginning to the end inclusively. Those created using ... exclude the end value.`

Comment: @LucasP, I didn't count the dots (possibly because I always use two), so my mistake.

Comment: I was struggling with figuring out why your suggestion wasn't working on my actual data, yet when I try with a vanilla string it works. I have updated the question with more details about what my data actually looks like.

Comment: Yeah i expected to be some character that seems like a space but its not. One way you could fix this method is by adding this special character as an argument to the split. So, change the split from `split()` to `split('&nbsp')`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more than one word, you can use a replacement:

```
'West Virginia Accountant'.sub(/\W+\w+\W*$/, '')
```

Comment: What are the downsides to using this approach? What are the cases that this will throw a false positive?

Comment: @marcamillion: it depends what you call "a word", for example this pattern will fail with a word with accented letters (but this can be solved easily with a few changes), or with a name that contains quotes like "Scarlett O'Hara" => "Scarlett O" or with acronyms "born in the U.S.A" => "born in the U.S", but you can change the pattern to `/\p{Z}+\P{Z}+\p{Z}*$/` (where `\p{Z}` matches all unicode separators).

Answer (score 0):

```
"New York Accountant".split().reverse.drop(1).reverse.join(" ")
```

Comment: Isn't `split[0..-2]` more direct than `split().reverse.drop(1).reverse`?

Comment: I was struggling with figuring out why your suggestion wasn't working on my actual data, yet when I try with a vanilla string it works. I have updated the question with more details about what my data actually looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
str = ['Chicago CPA', 'New York CPA', 'West Virginia Accountant']

str.map{|s| s[0...s.rindex(' ')]}
```

output: `["Chicago", "New York", "West Virginia"]`

Using Regexp.

```
str2 = "West Virginia Accountant"
p str2[/(.*)\s/,1]
```

output: `"West Virginia"`

Comment: I was struggling with figuring out why your suggestion wasn't working on my actual data, yet when I try with a vanilla string it works. I have updated the question with more details about what my data actually looks like.

Comment: @marcamillion in your actual string it contain '&nbsp;'. so my regex cannot detect that. so u can use regex `/\W+\w+\W*$/`. can u past your actual string?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex `/^(.*)\s+\w+\s*$/` to capture everything but the last word:

Example:

```
str =  <<~EOF
        Chicago CPA
        New York CPA
        West Virginia Accountant
EOF

str.each_line do |line|
        puts line.match(/^(.*)\s+\w+\s*$/).captures.first
end
```

Output:

```
Chicago
New York
West Virginia
```